# Is it possible to use .htaccess to make custom Index Of pages? If so how?

Tags: php, .htaccess, indexing, indexof, directory-listing

You know how when you go to a url on a server and the directory doesn't have an index.* file or a default.* file it shows you a list of the directorie's contents? I was wondering if there is any way to customize the way that index looks or theme it to fit your site. For instance I'd want to add the php

```
<?
include 'template.php';

head();
?>
```

Before the listing. And

```
<?php
foot();
?>
```

After. Can this be done?

Comment: Sure, you can add your own `DirectoryIndex` file which can even be PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never done this before, but this shows how to do it: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3589651.htm via .htaccess.

Edit: Maybe [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20080815220844/http://howto.unixdev.net/dirlist.html) (snapshot) shows exactly what you want, it's a walk-through of how to embed header and footer in the listing page.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can add your own `DirectoryIndex` file which can even be PHP.

In you `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex my-dir-listing.php
```

Do inside the `my-dir-listing.php` file whatever you need to do the directory listing.

If you want to modify the header of the existing listing, take a look into the [`HeaderName` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername).